# MVN is expecting an older version of ASDF

Tags: maven, asdf

When I try to run `mvn validate`, I get the following error.

```
/Users/syncmaster/.asdf/shims/mvn: line 3: /usr/local/Cellar/asdf/0.9.0/libexec/bin/asdf: No such file or directory
/Users/syncmaster/.asdf/shims/mvn: line 3: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/asdf/0.9.0/libexec/bin/asdf: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

However here is the details of my asdf

ASDF Version

```
$asdf --version
v0.10.1

$whereis asdf
asdf: /usr/local/opt/asdf/libexec/bin/asdf

$ls /usr/local/Cellar/asdf
0.10.1
```

From brew:

```
brew info asdf
asdf: stable 0.10.1 (bottled), HEAD
Extendable version manager with support for Ruby, Node.js, Erlang & more
https://asdf-vm.com/
/usr/local/Cellar/asdf/0.10.1 (168 files, 714.3KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2022-05-19 at 10:42:28
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/asdf.rb
```

My `.zshrc` has the following line.

```
. /usr/local/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh
```

How can I fix my ASDF version so that maven uses the correct one?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using asdf ? I don't understand the need for that?

Comment: I use `asdf` to manage my software versions. I use asdf for managing Java, Python, Maven versions.

Comment: How many versions of Maven do you use? Apart from that you could install Maven once and use... and maybe when next release comes out you can upgrade to a newer version?  Furthermore Maven does not use any kind of this things?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by reinstalling maven using asdf.

Here is why I need ASDF for my Maven installation - I need Maven 3.6.3 and homebrew only supports 3.5 and 3.8. Instead of installing Maven manually, I prefer using ASDF to take care of the installation.

Uninstalled Maven first

```
asdf uninstall maven 3.6.3
asdf plugin remove maven
```

Reinstalled Maven

```
asdf list all maven 3.6
asdf install maven 3.6.3
asdf global maven 3.6.3
```